# iCloud Core Data Reliability & Timing

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, icloud

I have been attempting to implement iCloud with my Core Data based small business apps.  Been using a GitHub method called Ubiquity Store Manager (USM) and more generic Apple code example methods.  It almost seems to work...but there are 2 major issues that I can't seem to consistently address:

**Timing** - When the context is saved to the Ubiquity container it is beyond your control to determine when it is upload to iCloud.  If two transactions are saved in less than 3-5 seconds often they will be uploaded to iCloud in the reverse chronological order they were entered/saved.  For example: trans1 at 8:01:01 and trans2 at 8:01:04, trans2 will often upload and download onto other devices BEFORE trans1.  If these are simple records like appointments or contacts, probably not a big deal.  With parent-child related records it's a very big deal as the child records arrive before and parents and are effectively "lost" in iCloud.  I have tried a timer between transactions 5-7 second delay will eliminate the problem, but is there a better way to handle this?

**Reliability** - When testing on 2 devices after a pause of as little as 2 minutes, if 2 successive transactions are saved frequently the first transaction will not be displayed on the 2nd device.  If a "wake up" transaction is created prior to the entry of the real transaction then the reliability can be restored.  Again, this is a kluggy solution, does any one have a better way to handle this?

Key Value iCloud transaction are almost instantaneous, error free and bulletproof.   How can this be achieved using Core Data or is Core Data just not appropriate for complex (multiple relationship) business transactions?

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: I gave up long ago on trying to use the builtin Apple iCloud support for Core Data.  It was so broken, and cost me so much time, that I switched to using Ensembles, and have never looked back.  Ensembles supports using iCloud as a backend so you can synch with it just fine.  Here is the link: http://www.ensembles.io/  Note that I have ZERO affiliation with Ensembles, aside from being a happy paying customer for the paid version 2.  It was worth every penny,  Version 1 is free, open source, and available on github.

Comment: I'm using cloud kit, which is much more work, however it is reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses!  CloudKit does deal with the relationship issue, however each of my users would need their own container and I would still need core data for the app.  Ensembles sounds interesting.  I have checked out some other products and again each of my users needed their own account which got cost prohibitive.    iCloud Documents seems solid so I am considering saving records as iCloud Document and then downloading them to the other devices and recreating the Core Data table and relationships. At least I can control the process this way.  Thanks again!